# What is the PLAYERUNKNOWN SET?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Currently on steam market there is an item that is very expensive called ["PLAYERUNKNOWN SET"](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/578080/PLAYERUNKNOWN%20SET).

I assume this is a skins case but what does it contain and how does it work?

Comment: Pretty expensive item for a game in early access...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be the preorder rewards according to discussion [on the forum](http://forums.playbattlegrounds.com/topic/6258-playerunknowns-costume-set/)

> It's the item that you received if you pre-ordered the game. It includes all the PU clothes like the trench coat, scarf, etc.

Further backed up by [a news article](https://pvplive.net/c/playerunknowns-battlegrounds-steam-trade-market) about PLAYERUNKNOWN's cosmetic items becoming available on the Steam market. Note that:

> If you wanted to get the full set of PLAYERUNKNOWN cosmetic items, it's best if you buy the pieces separately. Other players are posting the unboxed full set for just under $400.

Comment: That appears to be what it is, would have made sense to put that in the item description seeing as it is marketable!